# Functions from my own developed R library not working

Tags: r

I created some functions and try to build a package/library, but run into some problems. I hoped to get some advise here on this support site.

This is how I tried to built my package.

I had some functions in an R file, including roxygen2 comments.

Then in R

```
library("devtools")

library(roxygen2)

setwd("C:to/my/directory")

create("myPackage")
```

Then I put my functions file in the R folder and changed the DESCRIPTION file.

```
setwd("./myPackage")

document()

setwd("..")

install("myPackage")

library(myPackage)
```

Then, when I want to see how a function works

```
?function1
```

I see the documentation in my browser.

But when I want to use my function I get an error.

```
function1
Error: object 'function1' not found
function1()
Error: could not find function "function1"
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am using R 3.3.1 on Windows 7.

Your help or comments are appreciated, thanks in advance!

Ben

Comment: Please show the code and roxygen2 markup for the function.

Comment: You probably need to add @export to your function documentation

Comment: I wasn't aware of the @export tag. It worked!